# Components of list

Tags: r

```
dfmerge_BR = read.csv(file ="dfmerge_BR.csv", header=TRUE)
dfmerge_CO = read.csv(file ="dfmerge_CO.csv", header=TRUE)
dfmerge_BL = read.csv(file ="dfmerge_BL.csv", header=TRUE)
dfmerge_KC = read.csv(file ="dfmerge_KC.csv", header=TRUE)
dflist <- list(dfmerge_BR,dfmerge_CO,dfmerge_BL, dfmerge_KC)

new_list <-  lapply(dflist, function(x) x[1,])

}
```

I have four different csv files here, I read them and put them into the list. I  iterated through the list of data frames such that I choose first row of each data frame(now the component of list) and assign them to new_list.
Now I want to extract the each component of list.
but when I do

```
a <- new_list[[1]]
b <- new_list[[2]]
```

When I view both the vectors, vector b has all the values as NA and also why the a and b aren't data frames but vectors?

Comment: `lapply(dflist, head, 1)` maybe?

Comment: Returns the same result as @seekheart answer i.e. a vector not a list!

Comment: `lapply` returns a list by definition. I have no idea what are you talking about. Try `class(lapply(dflist, head, 1))`. A list is a vector too btw. And a `data.frame` is a list too. Try `lapply(lapply(dflist, head, 1), is.list)` so your statement is invalid.

Comment: Yeah, I was mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want the first of every data frame then do this.

```
new_list <- lapply(dflist, function(x) x[1,])
```

Comment: Or just ```lapply(dflist, `[`, 1,)```